# Create AWS S3 Buckets in my web application users

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam

I am developing a Django Web Application. Is there a way that I can create buckets in my users AWS S3 accounts using Boto3.

Comment: Do you want to create the bucket in your **users'** AWS accounts?  Or do you just want to create a bucket for each user in an AWS account that you control?

Comment: I want to create in other users aws s3 account. Not in my account!

Comment: Do you have access keys for the other accounts? Or do you want to use cross account roles?

Comment: No I don't have access key of other account!!! How to use cross account roles?

Comment: You or the other users login to the other accounts and create an IAM role that give you  permissions to assume that role from your account. The boto3  assume_role() function (located in the service STS) gives you temporary credentials to access the other account.

Comment: @JohnHanley if i have multiple users giving me access how do i know which user has given me access?

Comment: Because they will either give you a login and password, or they give you an account number and a cross account role.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [AWS S3 Boto3 SDK](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html) to create buckets. For example to create bucket in your code you can use the following.

```
response = bucket.create(
    ACL='private'|'public-read'|'public-read-write'|'authenticated-read',
    CreateBucketConfiguration={
        'LocationConstraint': 'EU'|'eu-west-1'|'us-west-1'|'us-west-2'|'ap-south-1'|'ap-southeast-1'|'ap-southeast-2'|'ap-northeast-1'|'sa-east-1'|'cn-north-1'|'eu-central-1'
    },
    GrantFullControl='string',
    GrantRead='string',
    GrantReadACP='string',
    GrantWrite='string',
    GrantWriteACP='string'
)
```

Note: Make sure you configure the required IAM permission for the code execution.

**To Create the bucket in Users Account**

To create the bucket in an external AWS Account, you need implement a mechanism to authorize the creation through temporary access tokens or cross account bucket access ACL, or Cross Account Access Role from the users AWS account.

Comment: I need to create on my users aws s3 account. Not in my s3 account

Comment: To create the bucket in an external AWS Account, you need implement a mechanism to authorize the creation through temporary access tokens or cross account bucket access ACL from the users AWS account. The implementation depends on the ability of the user on granting access.

Comment: Can I generate temporary access tokens thought boto3 sdk? Is there anything like there in Google where it uses oauth to Grant access to Google drive?

Comment: Yes, Amazon has Cognito. Cognito Identities can issue temporary credentials to users.